# Check for the value of a CSS property

Tags: javascript, angular

I use `opacity: 0` for my class `.best-match`.

The CSS (Sass) looks like this:

```
.best-match
  opacity: 0
```

This is what I see in my browser:

```css
.best-match[_ngcontent-tli-c4] {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I would like to check with JavaScript if the property is set to 0. I have tried it with

```js
if (document.querySelector('.best-match').style.opacity === '0') { ... }
```

but the output is always false. I have also tried it with `@ViewChild()`:

```js
if (this.bestMatchContainer.nativeElement.style.opacity === '0') { ... }
```

but that also returns false. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style property only works for inline styles (the value of the style attribute on that element) on that element. If you want to look at all the styles that are effecting the element (including styling from css) look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). This might give you something that looks like this:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.best-match')).opacity === 0) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Window.getComputedStyle()` function.

```
const element = document.querySelector('.best-match);

if (window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('opacity') === 0) {
    // try something
}
```

Official guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle